# VS2008 asp.net spits out gibberish, possibly wrong encoding issue.

Tags: asp.net, encoding, debugging

I have inherited a project, it was originally written in VS2005.
I have made a few changes, but all are design.
Now when I run the project using the visual studio's web server, in IE8, the page shows up just fine, however in FireFox 3.6.3, I get gibberish (a full page of this):

> �`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$ؐ@�����iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼
>   ��{���{��;�N'���?\fdl��J�ɞ!���?~|?"~������˓7����t�.���WO����
>   m߽��{'w�>}�4������x'}��Ŵ�{���G�G�]=�{���j|uo\�w߼��Pv���

My setup:
Windows 7 Proffesional (All patches)
VS2008 SP1 (I think all patches)

Thank you for your help!
-Edward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved!
Pages had this tag:

Removing this fixed the gibberish.

-Edward